# Facbeook events from public page are empty

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I want to get all the events from a public Facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/vaitmusik/events

Using the offical module I will always get back an empty array.

```js
const FB = require("fb");

FB.api(
  "oauth/access_token",
  {
    client_id: "123456789",
    client_secret: "9c88casdasfdsfsdfasd",
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
  },
  function(oAuthResponse) {
    FB.api(
      "/Vaitmusik/events",
      {
        access_token: oAuthResponse.access_token,
      },
      function(eventsResponse) {
        /*  
          eventsResponse

          { data: [] }

        */
      }
    );
  }
);
```

I expected to have an array with all the events.

Comment: hopefully that code is not client side? (having the secret in it)

Comment: No this is server side.

Comment: ok, in that case it´s alright :) anyway, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/

> This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time.

In other words, it is not possible to get Page Events.